# Why is ~size_t(0) (== 0xFFFFFFFF in most 32-bit systems) not a valid array index?

Tags: c++, c, memory

Quoting from this blogpost:

http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2008/10/13/writing-64-bit-safe-code/

> This works because a valid memory index can only be in the [0, ~size_t(0)-1] range. The same approach, for example, is used in std::string.

So why is `~size_t(0)` (this should usually equal `0xFFFFFFFF` in 32-bit systems) not a valid array index? I assume that if you have 32 bits you should be able to reference the whole range [0, 0xFFFFFFFF], no?

Comment: Beats me. I've never heard of that restriction. I know Windows reserves the upper half of addresses (high bit set to 1) for itself, but that's just a policy thing.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is an invalid array index but you forgot to mention in your analysis the fact that you then subtract 1 from that: which gives 0xFFFFFFFE

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:** The term "memory index" is ambiguous and confusing.  The linked article refers strictly to array indexes, not addresses in memory.  It is entirely valid for `size_t` to be incapable of representing all memory addresses, which is why we have the `intptr_t` type in C99.  Of course, this doesn't apply to your workstation, which undoubtedly has a simple Von Neumann type architecture.  *(The question has since been edited to remove references to "memory indexes".)*

The C standard guarantees that `size_t` can hold the size of any array.  However, for any array `a[N]`, the standard guarantees that `a + N` must be a valid pointer and compare not equal to any pointer to an element of `a`.

Therefore, `size_t` must be able to represent at least one value larger than any possible array index.  Since `~(size_t)0` is guaranteed to be the maximum `size_t` value, it is a good choice of sentinel for array indexes.

**Discussion:**

1. *Why is `~(size_t)0` guaranteed to be the maximum?*  Because the standard explicitly says so: from §6.5.3.3: "If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression `~E` is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus `E`."  Note that `(size_t)-1` is guaranteed to also be the maximum by the rules of conversion from signed to unsigned types.  Unfortunately, it is not always easy to find the definition for `SIZE_MAX` on your platform, so `(size_t)-1` and `~(size_t)0` are preferred. (Note that this is no longer true if `int` can represent `SIZE_MAX`… but this isn't something that would happen in a real system.)
2. *What is the size of an array indexed from 0 to ~0?*  Such an array cannot exist according to the C standard, by the argument outlined at the top of this post.
3. *If you `malloc(-1)`, the resulting memory region would have to start at 0.* (FALSE) There are a lot of really bizarre cases which the standard allows but one doesn't encounter in practice.  For example, imagine a system where `(uintptr_t)-1 > (size_t)-1`.  The C standard is worded in exactly the way it is because it doesn't just run on your PC, it runs on bizarre little DSPs with Harvard architectures, and it runs on archaic systems with byzantine memory segmenting schemes.  There are also some systems of historical interest where `NULL` pointers do not have the same representation as 0.

Comment: I'm amazed by the sheer mass of deleted answers that appeared below my post between when I started and finished composing my answer...

Comment: +1 well put.  Another way to say this: what would the size of an array indexed from 0...~0 be?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If `a + N` must be a valid pointer, what if `a` starts at exactly half the memory and you add three quarters? Also it doesn't make sense that size_t must be able to represent one value larger than any possible array index. Why is that? And there were three deleted answers.

Comment: Sure, `size_t` can hold the size of any array.  But it doesn't follow that the maximum allowable array size *must* be `size_t`.

Comment: @Seth if an array is indexed from 0..3 then its size (a value of `size_t`) will be 4. If it is indexed from 0..~0-1 then it can be ~0.  But if indexed from 0..~0, what would it be then?  0?????

Comment: @Oli: But it does hold that the maximum allowable array size is strictly less than `~(size_t)0`, which is what I wrote.

Comment: @Ray you can't "index" an array from 0..~0 because ~0 is outside the bounds of memory. It's like, it's indexing an array with length 4 with the number 4.

Comment: @Dietrich: Ah, I see.  The question is actually misleading; `size_t(0)` isn't being suggested as an invalid "memory index" at all, it's being suggested as an invalid **array** index.  Which is quite different.  So +1.

Comment: @Dietrich: So actually, the logic is very simple.  If 2^32-1 were a valid array index, then the array would have to start at address 0, which isn't possible.

Comment: @Oli not really. You can think of an array index as 0[N], which is essentially a memory index.

Comment: This answer is a bit challenging to read.  Maybe ASCII charts are in order? :)  So the issue is sizing vs indexing being off-by-one?  It seems this would be easier to answer if you limit the problem scope and pretend you're talking about 8-bit values...

Comment: @Seth: See my subsequent comment for why I believe there's an important distinction.

Comment: @Oli Well besides, even if you could have an array from 0..~0, you couldn't store the size anyway, so the question is moot :)

Comment: @Dietrich I would say that `SIZE_MAX` has that guarantee, but `!(size_t)0` depends on two's complement math. ;D

Comment: @Oli: NULL is not always 0, so sometimes 0 is a valid memory address.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: Since `size_t` is unsigned, bit arithmetic is guaranteed to work as you expect.  But yes, one normally does prefer `(size_t)-1`.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Well, `NULL` is actually always `0` (or `(void *) 0` in C). The actual *null-pointer value* that `0 ` transforms into in pointer context is not necessarily zero address, since, as you correctly noted, `0` can be a valid memory address.

Comment: @AndreyT: Well, `NULL` is only the *literal* 0, so `int x = 0; return (void *)x;` produces a different result than `return NULL;` on some systems.

Comment: @Dietrich Why does one prefer (size_t)-1 ? IMHO this is more confusing since you are casting a negative number to an unsigned type. If you happen to be on a platform that has 16 bit ints and 32 bit size_t then -1 would be 0xFFFF and (size_t)-1 would not be the same as ~size_t(0), no? The first would be 0x0000FFFF and the latter  0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @Mr. Roland: That is not how conversion works.  For example, on most systems, `(unsigned int)(short)-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF`, not `0xFFFF`.  Using -1 is preferable because you won't get the wrong result if you forget the cast, or put the cast in the wrong order.  For example, `size_t x = -1;` is equivalent to `size_t x = SIZE_MAX;`, but on 64-bit systems `size_t x = ~0;` is `0xFFFFFFFF` not `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @Dietrich thanks for clarification. But why does `size_t x = -1;` work as expected while on 64-bit systems `size_t x = ~0;` yields the wrong result?

Comment: @Mr. Roland: Er, whoops.  `~0` should yield the right result usually, but `~0U` will give the wrong result.  Tricky, isn't it?  When converting from signed to unsigned, the conversion is done relative to the target type.  When computing the complement, it is all done in the original type.

Comment: `~0` is correct only on twos complement systems. Conversion (explicit or implicit) from `-1` *really is* the correct way to get the maximum value of an arbitrary unsigned type.

Comment: @R..: See the quote from the C standard in the answer body which explains why `~0` is correct on all systems.

Comment: @R..: The reason why two's-complement versus ones-complement doesn't matter is because `size_t` is unsigned, and the difference between two's- and ones- complement is in the representation of signed numbers, not of unsigned numbers.

Comment: On a rare unicorn system where `int` is wider than `size_t`, `~(size_t)0` is greater than `SIZE_MAX`.  `(size_t)-1` is better.

Comment: @chux: This is incorrect, see §6.5.3.3 as cited in my answer. The C standard guarantees that `~(T)0 == (T)-1` if `T` is an unsigned integer type.

Comment: "If the _promoted type_ is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E." does not apply when `size_t` is narrower than `int` as in that obscure case, the promoted type is _signed_.  C does not specify  that `size_t` is as wide/wider than `int/unsigned`.  `(size_t)-1` does not have this problem and is preferable.

Comment: @chux: Okay, but remember that unicorns do not actually exist.

Comment: @chux: Also note that it is insufficient that `int` have greater rank, it has to have greater range, too.

Answer (score 14):

The intuition is this:

```
x = malloc(~size_t(0));    // the most you can allocate
x[~size_t(0) -1];          // the highest valid index
```

Comment: +1, this is the essence of the reason. ~0 is not a valid index because there are ~0 values. So ~0 is one byte past the bounds of memory.

Comment: Ooh, actually, hang on.  The C standard dictates that for an array of length `N`, `&x[N]` is valid.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Yes, &x[N] is valid but you are not allowed to dereference that pointer. Note that x[N] is not valid. Consider `&x[N] - &x[0] == N`

Answer (score 13):

Well, as @Apprentice Queue correctly noted in his answer, since the size of the largest continuous object in C or C++ program is limited by `SIZE_MAX` (same as `(size_t) -1`, same as `~size_t(0)`) he maximum index one'll ever need to index the bytes of that object is `SIZE_MAX - 1`. Yet at the same time, as @Dietrich Epp correctly notes in his answer, C and C++ allow address arithmetic one element beyond the end of the array, which makes `SIZE_MAX` a valid index, if not for accessing the array elements, then at least for pointer arithmetic. So, formally speaking `SIZE_MAX` is a valid index, even though it can't stand for an existing element of an array.

However, the whole idea of using `size_t` as a type that allows one to "index entire memory" is only valid within the bounds of some specific platform, where `size_t` does indeed happen to be sufficient for memory indexing ("flat memory" platforms like Win32, Win64, Linux belong to this category). In reality, from the general point of view, type `size_t` is not sufficient for memory indexing. Type `size_t` is only guaranteed to be sufficient for indexing bytes in a single continuous object in C or C++ program. Neither C nor C++ guarantees to support continuous objects that cover the entire address space. In other words, type `size_t` is guaranteed to be sufficient to index any explicitly declared array object in C/C++ program, but it generally is not guaranteed to be sufficient for counting nodes in a linked list. Yet, under assumption that on some specific platform the range of `size_t` does cover the entire memory, the value of `(size_t) -1` looks like a good choice of the "reserved" value, since this index can only stand for the last byte in the array of bytes covering the whole address space. Obviously, no one will ever need this index in practice for the actual indexing.

Nevertheless, if you are really interested in a formally appropriate type that can index the entire memory (and, consequently, is able to store the number of elements in any in-memory container), that would be `uintptr_t`, not `size_t`. The author of that blog post does seem to understand the general issue here, since he notes that `size_t` is not good for indexing files (i.e. for storing file sizes or offsets). However, it still would be nice to note that for pretty much the very same reasons type `size_t` is not appropriate for indexing memory as well. Type `size_t` is not really related to RAM or process address space, contrary to what the author claims in his blog entry. Type `uintptr_t` is related to process address space, but not `size_t`. The fact that `size_t` is sufficient on the platforms he mentions is nothing more than a specific property of those platforms.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I would mark this one as valid too but I can mark only one :(

Comment: "same as (size_t) -1, same as ~size_t(0)" --> [practically always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302602/why-is-size-t0-0xffffffff-in-most-32-bit-systems-not-a-valid-array-index?rq=1#comment80241375_7302650)

Answer (score 1):

Yes; I have read all of the answers so far. I will now add a simple example with only 2 significant bits. The maximum representable 2 bit unsigned value is 3 which means we can allocate, at best, 3 units of storage.

The indices to the units are: [0, 1, 2] - notice that the maximum value of 3 is not within the addressable range because it is not possible to allocate storage that large with only 2 bits.

The root cause for this is that the indexing in C and C++ start from zero. The indices are "off by one" because size of 1 overlaps offset of 0. This causes the indices with same number of bits reach one element further than the size.

That's the ELI-5 version of the answer.

Practical examples:

char buffer[4]; // ERROR: 4 is not presentable with 2 bits

uint32_t buffer[1]; // HACK: we allocated 4 chars.. now what?

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302650/2445184) is perfectly correct, of course. However, I want to add a *technical* reason to it: It is plain impossible to allocate an array so large that `~size_t(0)` could index into it.

The point is, that there are at least a few bytes of code mapped into your address space at any time, so you simply do not have the entire virtual address space at your disposal for mapping your array. (And I didn't even mention the allocations for stack space and the null page!) You see, the only place that an array that can be indexed with `~size_t(0)` could be mapped is address zero, and it would extend across every single byte of virtual memory, so that the very last byte could be indexed. This is plain impossible to achieve.

Also consider this: Your CPU does not care for sign when adding numbers. To the CPU, adding `~size_t(0)` to a value is the same as *decrementing* that value by one. And decrementing any pointer by one points it outside of its allocated memory range, unless it is the `null` pointer which cannot point to a valid memory range...

The restriction of the language standard that allocations can not be larger than `~size_t(0)` is much weaker than these technical restrictions.

Comment: Last sentence, you mean "can not be `~size_t(0)` or larger "

Comment: @Roland The standard allows you to allocate `~size_t(0)` bytes (=0xffff ffff on 32 bit), which is exactly one byte less than the virtual address space can hold (=0x1 0000 0000 on 32 bit). The size of the virtual address space can not be expressed as an integer of type `size_t`.